# Table with sticky header and fitting text

Tags: java, user-interface, codenameone

I tried to find how to make a table with a simple sticky header and all I found was [this blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sticky-headers.html), which is nice, but goes far beyond what I need - I need just a single sticky header line and scrollable content, which should be trivial....

My second table-related problem is that I need to display lines with a different fields

```
| XYZ | Lorem ipsum long long long line foo bar blah ipsum dolores est. | 7 | - |
| PQR | Ceterum autem censeo Carthaginem esse delendam.                 | 3 | ✓ |
```

where the long text should be cut off as needed, while the short fields must be shown in full. I could find the widest text or use "WWW", then add padding (and maybe something else?) to get the proper width constraint... or should I subclass `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two tables and define the column widths with percentages so they match. This will solve both of your requirements:

```java
Container twoTables = BorderLayout.center(mainTable);
twoTables.add(NORTH, headerTable);
```

To define the width:

```java
protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(Object value, int row, int column) {
    TableLayout.Constraint con = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
    return con.wp(COLUMN_WIDTHS[column]);
}
```

Comment: You moved my second problem into `COLUMN_WIDTHS`. The width for the narrow columns must be so that all the texts fit. So given my above example (assuming just the two rows), what is `COLUMN_WIDTHS[0]` so that neither `XYZ` nor `PQR` get cut off?

Comment: That's a bit tricky since it depends on screen/font size but if the font size is in millimeters you can probably define a size in percentage that will fit all results. I'd do this with a bit of trial and error for various sized DPI's/screens in the simulator.

Comment: A "bit of trial and error" will break once someone improves the font sizes (I haven't touched them yet). I guess, I'll do some computation instead.... unfortunately, `TableLayout.layoutContainer` is a small monster not meant to be customized. I could imagine combining absolute width and percentage, possibly also with some `max`, so that it looks good on wide screens, too (one day, there'll a desktop version). For now, I'll try to compute the percentage using `Font.stringWidth("WWW")`.

Comment: An alternative approach is to invoke `Component.sameWidth(...) ` on all the components in the problematic column (including the header) and then avoid percentage in that column and for one column that can "grow". Haven't tries it myself but it should work in theory. You can also set percentage to -2 to indicate that this column should take up available space.